# Counting the number of domino tilings for a rectangular grid

Tags: c++, combinatorics

A [domino tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domino_tiling) of a grid is a tiling of the grid using domino pieces. Below is a C++ program to count the number of possible tilings of a grid of a given size.

The program constructs the board row by row, representing each row as a string. In each row, `d` represents the top half of a domino pointing downwards, `u` represent the bottom half of a domino pointing upwards, `r` represents the left half of a domino pointing to the right, and `l` represents the right half of a domino pointing to the left.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class DominoTilingCounter {
    int height, width;
    bool done;
    int tilingCount;

    map<string, vector<string>> dictionary;

    vector<string> firstRow(int width) {
        vector<string> prev;

        prev.push_back("d");
        prev.push_back("r");

        for (int col = 1; col < width; col++) {
            vector<string> next;

            while (!prev.empty()) {
                string candidate = prev.back();
                prev.pop_back();

                switch (candidate.back()) {
                case 'd':
                case 'l':
                    next.push_back(candidate + 'd');
                    if (col != width - 1)
                        next.push_back(candidate + 'r');
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    next.push_back(candidate + 'l');
                    break;
                }
            }

            prev = next;
        }

        return prev;
    }

    vector<string> nextRows(const string& row) {
        if (dictionary.find(row) != dictionary.end())
            return dictionary[row];

        vector<string> prev;

        if (row.front() == 'd')
            prev.push_back("u");
        else {
            prev.push_back("d");
            if(row.length() > 1)
                prev.push_back("r");
        }

        for (int col = 1; col < row.length(); col++) {
            vector<string> next;

            while (!prev.empty()) {
                string candidate = prev.back();
                prev.pop_back();

                switch (row[col]) {
                case 'd':
                    if (candidate[col - 1] != 'r')
                        next.push_back(candidate + 'u');
                    break;
                case 'u':
                case 'r':
                case 'l':
                    if (candidate[col - 1] == 'r')
                        next.push_back(candidate + 'l');
                    else {
                        next.push_back(candidate + 'd');
                        if (col != row.length() - 1)
                            next.push_back(candidate + 'r');
                    }
                }
            }

            prev = next;
        }

        return prev;
    }

    int countTiling(int height, int width, const string& previousRow, int currentRow) {
        if (currentRow == height) {
            for (char cell : previousRow)
                if (cell == 'd')
                    return 0;
            return 1;
        }

        int count = 0;

        vector<string> rows;

        if (currentRow == 0)
            rows = firstRow(width);
        else
            rows = nextRows(previousRow);

        for (string row : rows)
            count += countTiling(height, width, row, currentRow + 1);

        return count;
    }

public:
    DominoTilingCounter(int height, int width) : height(height), width(width) {
        if (height <= 0 || width <= 0 || height * width % 2) {
            tilingCount = 0;
            done = true;
        }
    }

    int count() {
        if (!done) {
            tilingCount = countTiling(height, width, "", 0);
            done = true;
        }

        return tilingCount;
    }
};


int main() {
    DominoTilingCounter tc(4, 7);

    cout << tc.count() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a decent translation of your algorithm into C++. However, if you're looking for speed, this code is very "heavyweight".

- It uses strings such as `"drldurlrld"` to represent each row of the grid, when bit-strings would suffice. (If you mark each `"d"` with the bit `1`, and everything else with the bit `0`, you'll still have an unambiguous encoding. This trick is similar to the trick used by [Eller's maze-generation algorithm](http://weblog.jamisbuck.org/2010/12/29/maze-generation-eller-s-algorithm).)
- It copies around `vector<string>` to memoize the "next possible rows" for a given row.
- It doesn't use move semantics.

---

Now, I said that your code memoizes "next possible rows" — this is the purpose of `dictionary` — but if you look closely, you'll see that the variable `dictionary` is unused!

I can tell from context that what happened is you forgot to add a single line of the form `dictionary[row] = prev;` at the end of `nextRows`. But if the compiler can't read your mind as well as I can, then you'll have to learn to be more on guard — otherwise your code will run slowly and you won't know why!

On the plus side, this one-line difference is nice because it means you can test your code with and without the memoization and see if the memoization is actually worth it. I think it will be worth it, but I'm not 100% sure.

---

```
    if (currentRow == height) {
        for (char cell : previousRow)
            if (cell == 'd')
                return 0;
        return 1;
    }
```

This code, which rejects tilings with dominos that stick off the bottom of the grid, is important enough that I would recommend putting a comment on it.

```
    if (currentRow == height) {
        // Count this tiling, unless it dangles off the edge of the grid.
        return (previousRow.find('d') == std::string::npos) ? 1 : 0;
    }
```

---

To address the lack of move semantics: There are a couple of places in `firstRow` where you make *copies* of strings (or even whole vectors of strings), when you actually don't care about the right-hand side of the assignment anymore and might as well just *move* the string (or vector) into the left-hand variable. For example:

```
    string candidate = prev.back();
    prev.pop_back();

    switch (candidate.back()) {
    // ...
    case 'r':
        next.push_back(candidate + 'l');
        break;
    }
}

prev = next;
```

Here once you've finished the `switch` statement you don't care about the value of `candidate`, so you could

```
next.push_back(std::move(candidate) + 'l');
```

to save a copy. (Yes, this will in fact do the efficient thing: see overload #11 on [the cppreference page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B).)

And you *certainly* don't need to make a copy of `next` when you assign it to `prev`! Replace that vector copy with a quick vector move:

```
prev = std::move(next);
```

Move semantics are more subtle (and probably less important) than I'm making them sound here; I won't go into detail here. But there is no shortage of material for learning more about move semantics if you want/need to.

---

```
int count() {
    if (!done) {
        tilingCount = countTiling(height, width, "", 0);
        done = true;
    }

    return tilingCount;
}
```

This is a common anti-pattern I see in a lot of student code for some reason: you want to compute a value, so you make a `ValueComputor` class, give it a `computeTheValue()` method, and then add memoization so that the `computeTheValue()` method won't be so darn slow the second time you call it.

This is an anti-pattern because it takes a notionally *const* operation (counting the number of tilings) and makes it a *non-const* member function. That is, it breaks this reasonable-looking code:

```
DominoTilingCounter tc(4, 4);
const DominoTilingCounter& param = tc;
std::cout << param.count() << std::endl;  // oops! can't call count() on a const object!
```

But it's also super easy to fix. Just take that code that computes the number of tilings, and move it straight into the *constructor* of your class!

```
DominoTilingCounter(int height, int width) : height(height), width(width)
{
    if (height <= 0 || width <= 0 || height * width % 2) {
        tilingCount = 0;
    } else {
        tilingCount = this->countTiling(height, width, "", 0);
    }
}

int count() const { return tilingCount; }
```

Much cleaner! And a tiny bit faster in the case that you call `count()` multiple times, because you don't have to check `done` anymore. (And much slower in the case that you construct a `DominoTilingCounter` object and *never* call the `count()` method — but why on earth would you construct this single-purpose object if you're *never* going to use it?)

---

Now notice that you don't use `this->height` or `this->width` anywhere in the code — instead, you pass around the caller's original `height` and `width` as parameters. *And* with the refactoring above, you don't use `done`. So what you're left with here is a `class DominoTilingCounter` that is effectively the same thing as an `int`. So, get rid of the useless class!

```
int count_domino_tilings(int height, int width);
```

*This* is the function you want to be writing. There's no reason to drag object-orientation into it at all. Your main function had been multiple lines long because of the mutation involved (and honestly it's not clear from reading this code that all the expensive work occurs on line 2 — so that's another downside to the anti-pattern above)...

```
int main() {
    DominoTilingCounter tc(4, 7);
    std::cout << tc.count() << std::endl;
}
```

...but with a nice clean function, it becomes simply

```
int main() {
    std::cout << count_domino_tilings(4, 7) << std::endl;
}
```

With such a drastic savings in lines of code, you have room left over to write some test cases! :)

Comment: It would be worth pointing out that calling `count()` from the constructor works because it's not `virtual` and pointing out the pitfalls of calling `virtual` functions from a constructor.

Comment: I *don't* recommend calling `count()` from the constructor, and I certainly wouldn't recommend involving `virtual` member functions here!

Comment: Ah, re-reading it, I see my mistake. Sorry for the confusion!